# ID not showing in the parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a code that sends email to user. In the email, there's a link in there that they should visit with the corresponding ID in order for them to be directed to a certain page.

Here's my code:

```
public void Notify(int appr_id = 0)
{
    var check = db.rms_approval_routing.Where(s => s.appr_id == appr_id && s.appr_isactive == true).FirstOrDefault();
    try
    {
        if (check != null)
        {
            check.status_id = 8;
            db.Entry(check).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            var getinfo = db.rms_approval_route_vw.Where(s => s.appr_id == appr_id && s.appr_isactive == true).FirstOrDefault();
            var getpayment = db.rms_payment.Where(s => s.appr_id == appr_id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (getinfo != null && getpayment != null)
            {
                var ref_email = getinfo.ref_email;
                var cc_email = getinfo.user_email;
                var pay = getpayment.p_amount;
                var body = "";
                body = "Good day!<br><br>Please be informed that you have successfully referred &nbsp;<u>" + getinfo.Fullname + "</u> and you are entitled to receive <u>P &nbsp;" + pay + "</u> which will be credited on the next payout for your successful referral.<br>Kindly visit the link to acknowledge the payment: http://localhost:8119/ReferralLetter/Acknowledge/" + appr_id + " <br>Thanks!";
                SendEmailController email = new SendEmailController();
                email.SendReferrer(ref_email, cc_email, body);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }   
}

public ActionResult Acknowledge(int appr_id = 0)
{
    var check = db.rms_emails.Where(s => s.appr_id == appr_id && s.email_date_ack == null && s.email_isactive == true).FirstOrDefault();
    if (check != null) {
        ViewBag.email_id = check.email_id;
        ViewBag.appr_id = appr_id;
        return PartialView();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Denied");
}
```

In this line: `http://localhost:8119/ReferralLetter/Acknowledge/" + appr_id`

The `appr_id` value is 0 when I tried to breakpoint the `Acknowledge` function. When I received the email, it showed there this line: `http://localhost:8119/ReferralLetter/Acknowledge/23`

Meaning there's an ID in there but why in the `Acknowledge` function the ID was 0?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, that's why I'm wondering why the `Acknowledge` function doesn't accepts the ID. Why it is 0?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, try to take a look in the link in body message. There's a link in there where it calls the `Acknowledge` function.

Comment: I know that it is a localhost. I try to debug it in anyways. It works when I try to initialize the value of `appr_id` to 23 and it worked! So how should I passed the ID in the link then so that the value of `appr_id` will be 23 then?

Comment: So how should I define it? I just encountered this error this time.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much @StephenMuecke, you're so great!